# how to parse url add params in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom` to parse a url, my current URL

> localhost:3000/q=sldkfjsdlkjflksfd

but what I want is add a new param in url `&test=1`

> localhost:3000/q=sldkfjsdlkjflksfd&test=1

```js
const parsed = parse(window.location.search);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML Api  `URLSearchParams`,

```
componentDidMount(){
  let params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);  
  let q = params.get('q');
  let test = params.get('test');
}
```

Also, `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';` in your component if this.props.location is undefined and `export default withRouter(ComponentName);`

Comment: i try this but my componentName is connect to react-redux  export const Container = connect(
  mapStateToPros,
  { requestAuthentication }
)(ContainerCmp);  when should i add withRouter i get  null value to test and q